# Why is the return value of a function with a multisession future different in plumber?

Tags: r, future, plumber, r-future

When comparing the first two code snippets below it is apparent that the `do.call()` setup will not return `4` but rather an object from the `futureverse`. On the other hand the `plumber` setup seems to resolve this "automatically" and returns the `4` in the "Response body" of the API.

I'm aware that return values can be accessed via `future::value()` (see chunk three) but I don't understand why this seems to work automatically in `plumber`. Can someone clarify this?

Here is the code to run the function in `plumber` context:

```r
# put this code into the file plumber.R and run:
# plumber::plumb("plumber.R")$run(port=9999)
# click "Try it out" and then "Execute"
# the Response body shows the 4
future::plan(future::multisession)

#* @get /async_sqrt
function() {
  future::future({4})
}
```

Here is the code to run the function via `do.call()`.

```r
do.call(function() {
  future::future({4})
}, args = list())
```

To retrieve the `4` in `do.call()` context this needs to be adapted as so:

```r
do.call(function() {
  future::value(future::future({4}))
}, args = list())
```